# Google Fonts inside CSS file https link

Tags: css, https, google-webfonts

I am using Google Web Fonts inside my CSS stylesheet like below

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
     src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v6/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');}
```

but when my website goes from secured page, I am getting "only secured content is being displayed". I used Google Chrome Resource Inspector and it pointed above was the issue

How can I add a secured link to the Google Web font in my CSS file

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to change *http://* to *https://* in the last line of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need @font-face to use a Google Font.

Just add this in your HTML code:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Then add the font name in your CSS. Example:

```
body{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;}
```

Comment: Actually, it did not work for me. I had Open Sans with font-weight of 400 and 300. When I used the `<link...>`, The only IE and Chrome were able to render the correct fonts and FF could not. As soon as I changed it to using `@font-face`, it worked for FF as well

Answer (score 0):

Bit old but it came up on a related search so it may be useful to someone.

I personally put the @font-face declaration in my stylesheets rather than requesting it in the head. Just remove the 'http:' like below, should solve the problem.

```
url(//themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/...) format('woff');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use @import statement?

At the top of your css file:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
```